# Deploying React in Github page - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm making React App.

---

Firstly, I'm making deployment on GH page with **SASS** and now I have this problem. Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

*I don't know which code exactly I have to add , so just tell me what part of code i nee to add.*

[image]

[page with error](https://dmitriykulikovskiy.github.io/MyWebSite/)

Comment: What's the url of your page ?

Comment: @BENARDPatrick https://github.com/DmitriyKulikovskiy/MyWebSite/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should set the homepage property inside your `package.json`

Read this : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

It's because your website isn't at the domain's root.